# Saving score with Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, keychain

I am developing a game with Spritekit and I'm now at a point where I have to keep track of the user's highscore. There are various different methods for storage with the easiest one being NSUserDefaults, but it's recommend for preferences.

However, I found this Keychain wrapper which tends to save a string with a key:

https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

Do you think it's good to use it? My idea is to convert the score (Integer) to a String before saving it and while retrieving the highscore, I will convert it back from String to Int. Do you think it's a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantages of the key chain I can see are that entries persists when an app is deleted and can't easily be changed. UserDefaults would be tied to your app Id and lost on app delete: unless you used the global domain.

You could look to use CloudKit key/value storage to achieve cross device high scores, storing the data in the cloud. This would be more work and you would need to add conflict resolution.

Depending on how serious you are taking high scores, you should perhaps consider integrating with Game Center? Ideal if you want high score etc to persist across more than one device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html

Comment: What is the preferred amount of data that can/should be stored when using keychain as storage method? Thanks!

Comment: I would say you should only use it for items like passwords, virtual coins, high scores or small pieces of information you want to share (icloud keychain) and protect from being accessed easily through other mechanisms. Also for items you might need to survive an application reinstall as opposed to an application restart. Anything bigger should be going into the file system IMHO

Comment: Thanks for the response Rory. Yes, I will be integrating Gamecenter but I will first need to save the highscore locally before syncing it with Gamecenter. Isn't this the case? Because if there's no network connection, the app has to store it locally.

Comment: You are correct, but when using game center you would need to adjust how you do things to fit in with that service. Apple provides an example showing how to load scores including dealing with offline here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GKLeaderboards/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011368-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2